# Resuming Upload to BigQuery using the Pandas interface

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am using the [BigQuery python API](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/index.html) along with the [BigQuery connector for Pandas](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage/pandas.html).

Every time I `append` to the dataset in BigQuery I want to make sure I start from where I left of the last time to prevent duplicates and loss of data.

Is there a setting in [Load Job Config](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig) or somewhere else that would do this automatically? If not, how do you suggest I handle connection errors and upload reties while preventing data duplication? I know I could query the last row and append data based on that, but I prefer not to query since BigQuery charges for querying.

Here is what I have so far for uploading to BigQuery:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery, exceptions

test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
    'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
    'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8],
    'names': ['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish']
})
project = "test-project"
dataset_id = "test-dataset"
table_id = "test-table"
client = bigquery.Client()
try:
    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id=dataset_id, project=project)
    dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_ref)
except exceptions.NotFound:
    print("specified dataset not found! -- creating a new dataset.")
    dataset = client.create_dataset(dataset_id)

table_ref = dataset.table(table_id)
load_job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=test_df, destination=table_ref, project=project)
load_job.result()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you can generate **unique load-batch-id** over your source data.

One way to achieve your goal is:

1. Label your load job with load_batch_id

   [Client.load_table_from_dataframe](https://google-cloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.load_table_from_dataframe.html) has argument: **job_config** (google.cloud.bigquery.job.**LoadJobConfig**, optional)

   Inject load_batch_id into **LoadJobConfig.labels** (Dict[str, str] – Labels for the job.)
2. When you need to confirm if a load job was successful, use [job.list](https://google-cloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/usage.html#list-jobs-for-a-project) api to search for job with label load_batch_id.

One simplified case is, say, you load data only daily to BQ and your source data is groupable by date. Then your 20190325 python script starts with first checking job labeled 20190324 (or deeper into the past) to see if it needs a retry.